# Matching a complete word with JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to look for a word in a String.

```
re = new RegExp("bob");
checkWord = re.test("This is bobby!");
if (checkWord) { break; }
```

I want checkWord = false as I am only looking for "bob", but it checkWord = true as "bobby" contains the word "bob". What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should accept an answer and open a new question with the array because the title is `Matching a complete word` (which has an answer)

Comment: Okay Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: (Plus, there will be more people on your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with two different ways:

give boundries

```
\bbob\b
```

or group them

```
\b(bob)\b
```

Both will work.

This is the working example:

[Example](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31dvg)

And if you are working with array then loop through each and check individually.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. But I have a last question. How do I use boundaries with array. I tried re = "/\b("+nameArray[i]+")\b/"; It's not working..

Comment: @SherleneTan I was trying to do it and it's strange, I have the same problem : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/AhqC4/3/

Answer (score 2):

It should work by using word boundaries.

```
re = /\bbob\b/;
```

Comment: What if I have an array of names like..
    nameArray = new Array("bob","Ben","Don");
How do I put them into..
re = /\b"+nameArray[i]+"\b/;

Comment: You could just glue them together like `re = new RegExp("\b(" + nameArray.join("|") + ")\b");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following method for this purpose.

```
nameArray = new Array("Bob", "Ben", "Don");
for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    if(nameArray[i].indexOf("Bob") != -1)
    {
    alert("true");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("false");
    }
}
```